# Interesting grep match in bash

Tags: linux, bash

Can you explain why

This one gives $? = 1

```
echo "uus" | grep -w -o [0123456789]\*
```

and this one give $? = 0

```
echo "-uus" | grep -w -o [0123456789]\*
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regular expression can match an empty string.  The `-w` flag means that any match must be preceded by beginning-of-line or a non-word character, and followed by end-of-line or a non-word character.

In the case of `uus`, the beginning of line is followed be a word character, so `grep` can't match an empty string as a word there.  The end of line is preceded by a word character, so `grep` can't match an empty string as a word there.

In the case of `-uus`, the beginning of line is followed by `-`, which is a non-word character, so `grep` can match the empty string as a word between the beginning of the line and the `-` character.

Comment: Why does grep -wo [0]\* output two lines of output, but grep -o [0]\* succeeds and outputs zero lines of output?

Comment: I get zero lines of output from both of your `grep` commands, with either `uus` or `-uus` as the input.  `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1`

Comment: Why does quoting the regex make a difference as SiegeX pointed out? I fail to understand how lack of quoting makes a difference? Can you explain that please?

Comment: As I explained in my comment on SiegeX's (now deleted) answer, putting quotes around the regex makes `bash` pass the backslash through to `grep`.  Without the quotes, `bash` interprets and removes the backslash and `grep` never sees it.

Comment: But I have escaped the * by doing \\* Also what does the bash pass to grep without the quotes? Please let me know.

Comment: I'm guessing that you tried to put a backslash before the second star in your comment.  But stackoverflow, like `bash` and `grep`, treats the backslash as a special character.  You do understand that backslash is special to `grep`, right?  And that putting quotes around the regular expression makes `bash` treat the backslash as *not* special, right?

Answer (score 0):

grep is matching the zero length word between '-' and 'u'.

Comment: No, it's matching the zero-length word between the beginning of the line and the `-`.  A word match must be followed by a non-word character, and `u` is a word character.