# Odd grep behavior

Tags: bash, grep

Motivated by  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144090/interesting-grep-match-in-bash/9144139#comment11495596_9144139)  question, can anyone explain the following behavior?

```
$ echo "-uus" | grep -wo '[0]*' && echo matched
-uus

matched
$ echo "-uus" | grep -o '[0]*' && echo matched
matched
$ grep --version | sed 1q
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1
```

In particular, why does the second grep succeed, but generate no output?  And why does the first command have two lines of output?  I can understand the second line of output, but I do not understand the first.

Comment: I get only `matched` in both cases. http://sprunge.us/RTfM

Comment: Are you sure you haven't created an alias or shell function named `grep` (that presumably calls the real `grep`)?  Do you have `GREP_OPTIONS` in your environment?

Comment: I can reproduce the OP's output, grep 2.5.1 on OS X, under several shells (with no GREP_OPTIONS defined.)

Comment: This is happening on OS X (10.8.0), grep is /usr/bin/grep, GREP_OPTIONS are not defined.  I cannot understand how the OS would matter.

Comment: This might be related to a bug present in older versions of grep (my system runs 2.9). BTW, what does `echo aa | grep -o ^.` print for you?

Comment: @choroba: I get two lines of "a"

Comment: Rob Mayoff stated (in the comments to his answer in the above referenced question) that he does not get the same behavior with grep 2.5.1, so I doesn't seem that it could be a bug with old grep.  DSM is getting the same behavior on OSX, so the OS is somehow relevant.  Perhaps the build is different.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Yeah, that's the bug I discovered years ago. Newer versions of grep should not exhibit such behaviour.

Comment: I also get two lines of "a" with 2.5.1, but a git checkout of 2.10.66-75b7 I've just compiled works fine.

Comment: Yup... can reproduce with 2.5.1 on OSX 10.7.2, but the version from MacPorts (2.10) works as expected.

Comment: @Choroba Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were bugs in the older versions of `grep`. I reported one here:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=144980

Newer versions of `grep` do not exhibit the problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

### Question: Why does the `grep` succeed, but generate no output?

```
$ echo "-uus" | grep -o '[0]*' && echo matched
matched
```

### Answer:

The pattern `[0]*` means at least zero character. So `grep` says it finds it, even if the matched text is empty. `grep` used with option `-o` does not print empty matched string. The `man` page says:

> -o, --only-matching
>          Print  only  the  matched **(non-empty)** parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

You can even use an empty pattern, it outputs the same:

```
$ echo "-uus" | grep -o '' && echo matched 
matched
```

You can also test:

```
$ echo    | grep -o '' && echo matched || echo unmatched
matched
$ echo -n | grep -o '' && echo matched || echo unmatched
unmatched
```

However `grep` prints even the empty lines when the option `-o` is not used:

```
$ echo    | grep '' && echo matched || echo unmatched

matched
```

---

---

### Question: Why does the first command have two lines of output?

```
$ echo "-uus" | grep -wo '[0]*' && echo matched
-uus

matched
$ grep --version | sed 1q
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1
```

### Answer:

Looks like a bug in `GNU grep 2.5.1`

Comment: Yes, but if grep matches the empty string with -o, it seems like it ought to output a blank line rather than nothing.

Comment: I agree `echo | grep ''` prints a blank line. Rather than `echo | grep -o ''` prints nothing.  But this is correct: option `-o` does not print empty matched string. Thank you to point that. I update my answer. Cheers ;-)

Comment: Hi @WilliamPursell. Thanks to your comment => I have updated my answer. I hope this weired `grep` behavior is clear now for you ;-) See you. Cheers.